# DisplayName from Jira emails (Exchange Online)

Tags: office365, jira, exchange-server

We have been using on-premise Exchange and sending notifications from Jira with anonymous 25 port and it was working smoothly.

Recently during migration to the cloud we created mailbox for Jira in Exchange Online.

AND..

In mail header in both (on-prem and EXO) there is like:

From: "Some User (JIRA)" no-reply@jira.sofwarehouse.com

To: some.user@softwarehouse.com

BUT..

When it was sending from on-prem then we saw in Outlook DisplayName as 'Some User (Jira)' and now from EXO we see DisplayName: 'no-reply'..

Is there any chance to see 'FROM' in DisplayName in Exchange Online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Exchange Online is not allowing any authentication via IP - you had to create mailbox for that. And Exchange Online gets DisplayName from DisplayName attribute in Admin center, you should set desired username there. It will be ignore any name set as header in Jira software.
BR Alexey.